# Docked view of breakpoints in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints

I am trying to get a permanent view of breakpoints (or at least lasting until I remove it) docked next to the `Debugger` panel.  E.g. I would like it to take place of `Watches`, since I do not use watches much.  Currently, viewing breakpoints is done by clicking the small double circle icon in the Debugger but that pops a new large window that occupies most of the screen.  I would like a small and permanent view of breakpoints (just like the one in Eclipse).

Comment: This isn't properly supported yet, but you can express your support for this feature to Jetbrains by voting for this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118510

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you open up the `Favorites` tool window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) you will see the breakpoints.

You cannot put this window inside the `Debug` tool window but you can have it docked above or beneath (or anywhere you want).

Like this:

[image]

Or like this:

[image]

The last image shows the `Debug` window docked with the `Split Mode` Off while the `Favorites` window has `Split Mode` On

Comment: Are you 100% positive is it impossible to dock the big floating breakpoints window? Anywhere at all? As a window it stays on top and is very unwieldy, but I had to no luck docking it / stopping it from floating. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your anwser! Would be nice if one could also toggle the breakpoints in the favorites window but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 3):

`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `F8` works for me

Comment: `⌘` + `⇧` + `F8` Worked in mac.

Answer (score 1):

IDEA 2017.1.3 allows breakpoints to be edited (e.g enabled/disabled) from the Favourites window (right click, Edit breakpoint).